# Accept All Dns Requests in cPanel (or any)

Tags: dns, cpanel, whm

Assuming i have the subdomain(ex. park1.server.com) and i want to point another domains to the park1.server.com without having to manually adding to my WHM. Think of it as domain parking service. Can it be done with WHM, cPanel? Will it affect another domains hosting on the same server in some ways?

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get this done in two different ways. First of all, you need to create a site on a dedicated IP address then you can either (manually) generate a wildcard DNS entry and manually add it to named.conf or you can just run /scripts/parkeddomain (IIRC) for each domain name you want to add with the site you created as the username. It really depends on how many domains you are talking about and how flexible you want it (the first option handles lots of domains, but isn't flexible - the second is a bit more manual, but you can then manage the domain names through cPanel itself).